# Print function printing multiple times in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

My script for counting tables and rows in the word docx working well. My question is why my printing statement printing till the condition gets fail. I attached the image for your reference

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document("sample2.docx")
i = 0
for t in doc.tables:
    for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Test Type" and (ro.cells[2].text=="Black Box" or ro.cells[2].text=="Black-Box"):
            i=i+1
print("Total Black Box Tests are: ", i)

j=0
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        if row.cells[0].text=="ID":
            j=j+1
            print("Total no of Tables:", j)
```

Help me. Thanks!

Comment: just an indentation problem! move the print at the 0-indent level you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

Problem with indentation of last print statement
Try this

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document("sample2.docx")
i = 0
for t in doc.tables:
    for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Test Type" and (ro.cells[2].text=="Black Box" or ro.cells[2].text=="Black-Box"):
            i=i+1
print("Total Black Box Tests are: ", i)

j=0
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        if row.cells[0].text=="ID":
            j=j+1
print("Total no of Tables:", j)
```